# Creating a dictionary of frequencies from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, histogram, frequency

I've got

```
d = [(4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 2), (4, 4), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 1)]
```

but many times larger.

the first number in each tuple is the month and the second is the number of incidents. I need to add up the number of incidents for each month and compile the total number of incidents for each month. 
so far i have:

```
def histogram(L):
    y = {}
    for x in L:
        if x[0] in y.keys():
            y[x] = y[x] + x[1]
        else:
            y[x] = x[1]
    return y
```

I'm needing an output similar to 
y= {4=24} (it doesnt have to be a dictionary)
but with a range of numbers as list d is quite extensive

current output is

```
{(4, 2): 2, (4, 4): 4, (4, 1): 1, (4, 3): 3}
```

thanks

Comment: Is your data sorted by month?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yes it is actually, goes from 1 to 12

Comment: So what exactly do you find unsatisfactory about your code? How does the result differ from what you want?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it doesn't work at the moment, I'm not sure where the problem is

Comment: I edited in the output as it stands now @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a dict-comprehension here(considering data is sorted by months):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> {k: sum(x for _, x in g) for k, g in groupby(d, key=itemgetter(0))}
{4: 24}
```

To improve your your code first thing you should do is to remove the `.keys()` call(though it is not going to matter much here as we can only have 12 months) because simple `key in dct` searches the key in O(1) time. Another problem is that you're using `x` as key, but you're supposed to use `x[1]` as key:

```
def histogram(L):
    y = {}
    for m, c in L:            #take the advantage of tuple unpacking
        y[m] = y.get(m, 0) + c
```

If you're sure you're always going to need all 12 months in your dict, then initialize all the months first:

```
def histogram(L):
    y = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 13), 0)
    for m, c in L:          
        y[m] += c
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). I added some extra data to your example also.

```
d = [(4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 2), (4, 4), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 1), (5,1), (5,2)]

from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()

for x, y in d:
    counter[x]+=y
```

then `counter == Counter({4: 49, 5: 3})`

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it.

d = [(4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 2), (4, 4), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 1)]

def histogram(L):
  y = {}
  for t in L:

```
month = t[0]
freq = t[1]
try :
  y[month] += freq
except KeyError:
  y[month] = 0
  y[month] += freq
```

return y

print(histogram(d))

Comment: You should use a default dict, or at least test for the presence of the key. Also why assign zero and then increment it by frequency instead of just assigning frequency.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit the name of your variables

```
incidents = [(4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1),
             (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 2), (4, 4),
             (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 1), (4, 1),
             (4, 2), (4, 1)]
inc_by_m = {}
for m, n in incidents:
    inc_by_m[m] = inc_by_m.get(m,0)+n
print inc_by_m
# {4:24}
```

the straightforward code is based on the optional argument (here `0`) to the `.get()` method of a dictionary, `get` returns either the value indexed by the mandatory argument if it was previously set, or the optional argument if it was not.